# Captcha Text not Align Center

Tags: captcha, simplecaptcha

Captcha text generated by nl.captcha.servlet.CaptchaServlet doesn't allign center.Changing css of  tag doesn't work also.Is there any parameter like "align-text"?

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>Captcha</servlet-name>
        <display-name>Captcha</display-name>
        <servlet-class>nl.captcha.servlet.CaptchaServlet</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
            **<param-name>align-text</param-name>
            <param-value>center</param-value>**
        </init-param>
</servlet>
```

Comment: You should reconsider the tags on your question. I don't think this has anything to do with XML or XSLT as such.

Comment: i use xslt tag not xml.Because may be from xsl we can add img tag properties.

Comment: Yes, this is true. You may use XSLT to provide the parameter in the XML. But unless you find somebody who knows WHICH parameters are required by the `servlet nl.captcha.servlet.CaptchaServlet` you won't be able to fix your XSLT.

Comment: ok i delete xslt.thank you.